# Line break in an input box?

Tags: powershell, inputbox

I wrote a batch script in which an InputBox is required, first of all this is the code line:

`powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter your command: [*here i want a line break*] Example commands: [*and here i want a line break*] example command', 'Input box example')}" > %TEMP%\out.tmp`

How do I insert a line break there? Pls help me, searching for hours now.

Kind regards,
jcjms

Comment: jcjms, I hace removed some of your tags. This question is relevant only to a small part of your [[tag:powershell]] code, and to designing the [[tag:inputbox]] with a particular layout. It has nothing whatsover to do with a [[tag:batch-file]], the [[tag:command-prompt]], or a [[tag:messagebox]]. Please be more considerate when assigning tags to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox(\"Enter your command: `r`nExample commands: `r`nexample command\", 'Input box example')}"
```

or

```
powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter your command: {0}Example commands: {0}example command' -f [environment]::Newline, 'Input box example')}"
```

[image]

---

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135190/line-break-in-an-input-box/70135403?noredirect=1#comment123979091_70135403) commented.
There is no need to enclose the command in `& {..}`. You can simply put quotes around the command:

```
powershell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox(\"Enter your command: `r`nExample commands: `r`nexample command\", 'Input box example')"
```

or

```
powershell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter your command: {0}Example commands: {0}example command' -f [environment]::Newline, 'Input box example')"
```

Comment: @jcjms You're very welcome!